# How to add custom Login and Roles mechanizm to asp mvc 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have to admit. Even after reading quite a few tutorial on this new mvc 5 Identity and all that owin stuff I just can't figure it out.
My task is to implement login and roles listing from Stormpath (Stormpath.com) which is basially a web-store for users and groups. I have created a service that authenticates user & password against stormpath and returns roles/groups assigned to user.

I have also went to the ApplicationSignInManager that is created by default with a new mvc project in Visual Studio and substitutes the body with:

```
public override Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout) {
    return Task.Run(() =>
        new StormpathService(new Configuration()).AuthenticateUser(userName, password) != null ? SignInStatus.Success : SignInStatus.Failure);

}
```

The thing passes when user inputs data into login form o a page, but after that the application still thinks that I'm not logged in.

What else need to be done for asp mvc Identity mechanizm to respect custom way of authenticating users and roles management?

Answer (score 0):

This is the minimum I had to make to support logging in from Stormpath.

```
   public class ApplicationUser : IUser {
        public string ClientKey { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string NewsFilter { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager) {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }


    public class StormpathUserStore : IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, IUserRoleStore<ApplicationUser> {
        private readonly IStormpathService _stormpathService;

        public StormpathUserStore(IStormpathService stormpathService) {
            if (stormpathService == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("stormpathService");
            }
            _stormpathService = stormpathService;
        }

        public Task AddToRoleAsync(ApplicationUser user, string roleName) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task RemoveFromRoleAsync(ApplicationUser user, string roleName) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(ApplicationUser user) {

            var groups = _stormpathService.GetUserGroups(_stormpathService.GetUserUrlFromId(user.Id));
            return Task.FromResult(groups.ToArray() as IList<string>);
        }

        public Task<bool> IsInRoleAsync(ApplicationUser user, string roleName) {
#if DEBUG
            var configuration = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IConfiguration>();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(configuration.DebugUser)) {
                return Task.FromResult(configuration.DebugRoles.Split(',').Contains(roleName));
            }
#endif

            var isInGroup =
                _stormpathService.GetUserGroups(_stormpathService.GetUserUrlFromId(user.Id)).Contains(roleName);
            return Task.FromResult(isInGroup);
        }

        public void Dispose() {
        }

        public Task CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task UpdateAsync(ApplicationUser user) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task DeleteAsync(ApplicationUser user) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<ApplicationUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId) {
            var userData = _stormpathService.GetUser(_stormpathService.GetUserUrlFromId(userId));
            if (userData == null) {
                return Task.FromResult((ApplicationUser)null);
            }
            var user = new ApplicationUser {
                UserName = userData.UserName,
                Id = userId,
                ClientKey = userData.ClientId,
                NewsFilter = userData.NewsFilter,
                FullName = userData.FullName,
            };
            return Task.FromResult(user);
        }

        public Task<ApplicationUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    // Configure the application user manager used in this application. UserManager is defined in ASP.NET Identity and is used by the application.
    public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser> {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store) {
        }

        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options,
            IOwinContext context) {
            var manager =
                new ApplicationUserManager(new StormpathUserStore(ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IStormpathService>()));
            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager) {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true
            };

            // Configure user lockout defaults
            manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
            manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 15;

            var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null) {
                manager.UserTokenProvider =
                    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity")) {TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14.0)};
            }
            return manager;
        }
    }

    // Configure the application sign-in manager which is used in this application.
    public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string> {
        public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
            : base(userManager, authenticationManager) {
        }

        public override Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent,
            bool shouldLockout) {
            return Task.FromResult(
                new StormpathService(new Configuration()).AuthenticateUser(userName, password) != null
                    ? SignInStatus.Success
                    : SignInStatus.Failure);
        }

        public override Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent, bool rememberBrowser) {
            return base.SignInAsync(user, true, rememberBrowser);
        }

        public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user) {
            var result = user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager) UserManager).Result;
            return Task.FromResult(result);
        }

        public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options,
            IOwinContext context) {
            return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
        }
    }
```